# ASP.Net: Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '='

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a compilation error while running the solution ASP.Net: `Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '='`.

My code looks like this:

```
var i=1 ;
@i=i+1
```

Comment: That code is c#?

Comment: Hi Rameshkumar, When you want ask a question you must write about your goal then explain your problem/Error in detail so that we can answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

If  you are writing C# code inside `.cshtml` then try this.

```
@{
    var i = 1;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add C# code on .cshtml page, you must put that code or each part of your code inside the 
`@ { // code here }`.

Visit this link for a strong understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2